# How do the in-browser speechSynthesizer voices actually work?

Tags: browser, text-to-speech, webspeech-api, speechsynthesizer

I am trying to find information about how the speechSynthesis voices work in the [Web Speech API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API). I understand how to use them, but I cannot find any information about how the individual voices actually work. What kind of architecture is under the hood?

**Does anyone know of any documentation on the voices populated by the Web Speech API?** From what I've found, they are browser/operating system dependent, but I can't find an example of how a single one actually operates. I'd be happy to find any, but am particularly looking for information on the "Google UK English Male/Female" and "Google US English" voices.

I've read through the Web Speech API documentation and what I believe to be the relevant portions of the Chromium source code. I've googled a ton and asked GPT4 - but cannot for the life of me find the actual information about how these are working.

Appreciate any help/ideas of how to find this information!

Comment: https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/4443a372fc385f06425ae0b689e3889f2c444d47/content/browser/speech/speech_synthesis_impl.h#L21